# Using classes to create a sequential search in python with a counter function

Tags: python, list, class, python-3.x, counter

I am working on an assignment, and have made a big start but have no idea how to continue and am looking for some advice (not answers). Using the following classes:

```
class CounterList:
    __n_comparisons__ = 0

    def __init__(self, data=None):
        if data is None:
            self.data = []
        else:
            self.data = data
        self.__n_accesses__ = 0

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        self.__n_accesses__ += 1
        return self.data[i]

    def __setitem__(self, i, item):
        self.__n_accesses__ += 1
        if type(item) != CounterNode:
            raise ValueError("Only Counter objects can be placed in a CounterList")
        else:
            self.data[i] = item

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.__n_accesses__ += 1
        del(self.data[key])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        raise TypeError("You can't use the 'in' keyword with a CounterList")

    def __eq__(self, other):
        self.__n_comparisons__ += 1
        return self.data == other

    def insert(self, index, item):
        if type(item) != CounterNode:
            raise ValueError("Only Counter objects can be added to a CounterList")
        else:
            self.data.insert(index, item)

    def index(self, a=None):
        raise TypeError("You can't do that with a CounterList")

    def append(self, item):
        if type(item) != CounterNode:
            raise ValueError("Only Counter objects can be added to a CounterList")
        else:
            self.data.append(item)

    def get_accesses(self):
        return self.__n_accesses__

    @classmethod
    def get_comparisons(cls):
        return cls.__n_comparisons__

    @classmethod
    def reset_comparisons(cls):
        cls.__n_comparisons__ = 0

class MyString:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def __eq__(self, j):
        if type(j) != MyString:
            CounterList.__n_comparisons__ += 1
        return self.i == j

    def __le__(self, j):
        if type(j) != MyString:
            CounterList.__n_comparisons__ += 1
        return self.i <= j

    def __ne__(self, j):
        if type(j) != MyString:
            CounterList.__n_comparisons__ += 1
        return self.i != j

    def __lt__(self, j):
        if type(j) != MyString:
            CounterList.__n_comparisons__ += 1
        return self.i < j

    def __gt__(self, j):
        if type(j) != MyString:
            CounterList.__n_comparisons__ += 1
        return self.i > j

    def __ge__(self, j):
        if type(j) != MyString:
            CounterList.__n_comparisons__ += 1
        return self.i >= j

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.i)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        '''All other behaviours use self.i'''
        return self.i.__getattr__(attr)

class CounterNode:
    def __init__(self, word, count=1):
        self.word = MyString(word)
        self.count = count

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.word) + ": " + str(self.count)
```

I am required to write a sequential searching program, which produces the output in the format:

```
 ['hello': 3, 'world': 3]
```

Where each word in the list is checked against the words in the new list, and if the word is not present then the word is added to the list with a counter of 1, and if the word is in the list the program should simply add 1 to that words count.

The code I have so far is:

```
from classes_1 import CounterNode, CounterList

def word_counter_seq(words_list):
    my_list = CounterList()
    for new_word in words_list:
        i = 0
        q = 1
        if not my_list:
            new_counter = CounterNode (new_word, 1)
            my_list.append(new_counter)
        elif new_word == my_list[i].word:
            my_list[i].count +=1         
        elif len(my_list)>1:
            if new_word == my_list[i].word:
                my_list[i].count +=1
                i+=1
            elif new_word == my_list[q].word:
                my_list[q].count +=1
                q+=1
            else:
                new_counter = CounterNode (new_word, 1)
                my_list.append(new_counter)
        else:
            new_counter = CounterNode (new_word, 1)
            my_list.append(new_counter)

    return my_list
```

However with the code as it is now, it only returns the first two elements in the original list correctly, and any consequent items are returned with a counter of 1 and as separate items. For example:

```
['hello': 3, 'world': 3, 'test': 1, 'test': 1]
```

instead of:

```
['hello': 3, 'world': 3, 'test': 2]
```

Comment: @jbutler483: erm, that's not valid Python syntax.

Comment: Are you required to implement `CounterNode` and `CounterList`? They are considerable overkill for what you are trying to achieve. There are tools in the python API that could help you accomplish what you are trying to achieve much more easily.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I'm sorry, there were that many edits going on adding/removing tags, it was pretty hard to know what was going on! But anyway, Obviously I write in c#/java/newer programming languages that implement this, and so I shall formerly apologise for my "TIP", in which was designed to HELP the user (as with your own TIP). So yes, I was in the wrong, but I had good intentions in my comment - unlike SOME on this site, clearly.

Comment: when i'm lost, i'll take no driving directions over incorrect ones any day of the week, regardless of intention.

Comment: also, james, look at either the `Counter` class or `defaultdict`s to get an idea of how to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @acushner, if you were lost, how could you tell I'd given you the wrong directions, if I myself thought they were correct? Either you're bad with analogies, or you know yourself that the person is actually wrong, and say nothing to them, just ignore their directions and carry on.

Comment: Unfortunately I am required to use the CounterNode and CounterList classes, which is why I'm finding this challenging.

Comment: @jbutler483: I did not intend to offend; a smiley face should have been added. The only edit I made to the tags was to replace one very version-specific (but not needed) `python` tag and instead added the generic `python` and `python-3.x` tags so that people would actually see the post.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the classes your assignment asks you to implement, it seems the intention is to force you to use arrays (although a dict would probably be better here...). Think about it this way:

```
for each new_word in word_list:
    for each element in your_list:
         if new_word equals element:
              #do something
         else:
              #do something else
```

By doing that you eliminate the unnecessary
    if not list:
check and make your code a lot cleaner, so won't confuse yourself. However I noticed that your CounterList seems to measure how many accesses are using. So if what your assignment requires is a solution that minimises accesses then think about this list:

`'test', 'book', 'whatever', 'test'`

your idea of comparing adjacent elements won't work unless you make it like this:

`'book', 'test', 'test', 'whatever'`

Sorry this answer is a little vague, I don't want to spoil your homework for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have been working on the code using this foundation but unfortunately the code breaks on the line:

    for each element in your_list

as using the classes provided I am unable to call in onto your_list. I am looking for a way to write this part of the code without using in, but am coming across quite a few problems. Any help would be appreciated, and thank you again for the quick response :)

Comment: you can access them by index though, so just pretend its an array. something like for i in range(length_of_array): do something